# set error " errors : {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}" by Angular 4 validator

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, asynchronous, promise

Mobile mobileNumberValidator returns fine but the other two validators returns a null promise on errors. Cant identify the mistake i have done here. Please help.
Those two validators sets errors in formbuilder object as follows

errors
:
{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}

In form builder group

```
 this.empInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      'Mobile': [null, [Validators.required], [this.mobileNumberValidator.bind(this)]],
      'Private': [null,  [this.privateNumberValidator.bind(this)]],
      'Work': [null, [this.workNumberValidator.bind(this)]],  
    });
```

Validator Methods

```
  mobileNumberValidator(control: AbstractControl) {

        return new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (!this.isMobileNumberValid) {
              resolve({
                'phoneNumber': true

              })
            console.log(this.empInfoForm)
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          }, 10);
        })
      }
        workNumberValidator(control: AbstractControl) {

        return new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (!this.isWorkNumberValid) {
              resolve({
                'phoneNumber': true

              })
               console.log(this.empInfoForm)
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          }, 10);
        })
      }
        privateNumberValidator(control: AbstractControl) {

        return new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (!this.isPrivateNumberValid) {
              resolve({
                'phoneNumber': true

              })

                  console.log(this.empInfoForm)
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          }, 10);
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake I have done here. Custom validator binding should be the third parameter here.

```
this.empInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      'Mobile': [null, [Validators.required], [this.mobileNumberValidator.bind(this)]],
      'Private': [null,null,[this.privateNumberValidator.bind(this)]],
      'Work': [null,null,[this.workNumberValidator.bind(this)]],  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use promises, you should have 2 parameters in your callbacks :

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ...});
```

And when you want to set the error to true, you need to reject the promise :

```
if (!this.isMobileNumberValid) {
  resolve({'phoneNumber': true});
  console.log(this.empInfoForm)
} else { reject(null); }
```

Comment: It gives an "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): null" error

    workNumberValidator(control: AbstractControl) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!this.isWorkNumberValid) {
          resolve({
            'phoneNumber': true
  
          })
           console.log(this.empInfoForm)
        } else {
          reject(null);
        }
      }, 10);
    })
  }

Comment: Sorry, you should return false, forgot that :)

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you explain please ? :)

Comment: Replace `reject(null)` with `reject(false)`, validators work on booleans

Comment: Still its not working :( 
Still i get
 errors:
{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}

Comment: what does this mean ? Where do you see that ?

Comment: in the form builder object .

Comment: it should be   errors:{'phoneNumber': true} when there's an error

Answer (score 0):

```
In IONIC

if you facing issue in IONIC

error :- __zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)


======================== Sol




// use platform ready function, its must

 this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        // use promise like syntax not like this.appVersion.getVersionNumber()
       
     this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then((data) => {
            
            })

})
```